# i var undefined inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
//Server Functions
var socketArray = [];
var socketRcon = [];
for (var i = 0; i < serversConfig.serversArray.length; i++) {
    socketArray[i] = new Socket;
    socketArray[i].setEncoding("utf8");
    socketArray[i].setNoDelay();
    socketArray[i].setTimeout(1000);
    socketArray[i].connect(serversConfig.serversArray[i].port, serversConfig.serversArray[i].ip);
    socketRcon[i] = serversConfig.serversArray[i].rcon;
    socketArray[i].on("connect", function() {
        this.write(socketRcon[i] + "\n", "utf8");
        console.log("CONNECTED TO THE SERVER...");
    });
    socketArray[i].on("data", function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
    socketArray[i].on("error", function(err) {
        console.log("ERROR:" + err);
    });

    socketArray[i].on("close", function(err) {
        console.log("CLOSED:" + err);
    });
};
```

This is the code I have now to connect to multiple servers from a config file, and I need that each time the socket connects, I need to send a password to it. But 'socketRcon[i]' is undefined, why is that happening and how do i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because by the time that code is run, `i` is equal to `serversConfig.serversArray.length`, meaning `socketRcon[i]` is undefined.

Anchor your value:

```
for( var i=0; i<l; i++) (function(i) {
    // do stuff here
})(i);
```

Comment: I tried with: http://pastebin.com/LBkBRY5g , but apparently the loop didn't execute.

Comment: See http://jslinterrors.com/dont-make-functions-within-a-loop/ for the reason for having an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) in the loop and another option that is, in my opinion, more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just do:

```
serversConfig.serversArray.forEach(function(srvconfig) {
  var sock = new Socket();
  sock.setEncoding("utf8");
  sock.setNoDelay();
  sock.setTimeout(1000);

  socketArray.push(sock);
  socketRcon.push(srvconfig.rcon);

  sock.on("connect", function() {
    this.write(srvconfig.rcon + "\n", "utf8");
    console.log("CONNECTED TO THE SERVER...");
  });
  sock.on("data", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
  sock.on("error", function(err) {
    console.log("ERROR:" + err);
  });
  sock.on("close", function(err) {
    console.log("CLOSED:" + err);
  });

  sock.connect(srvconfig.port, srvconfig.ip);
});
```